# Какая временная сложность поиска в std::vector

Tags: алгоритм, vector, c++

Какая временная сложность поиска в std::vector

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Необходимо учитывать не только контейнер, но и алгоритм работы над ним. Если рассматривать худший случай, то необходимо обойти весь контейнер для поиска элемента в нем, т.е сложность O(n).
Если элементы контейнера отсортированы, то  можно использовать бинарный поиск, он даст сложность O(ln(n)).

Comment: а как организовать в контейнере бинарный поиск?